# css in combination with rails 3 cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, cocoon-gem

I want to adjust the position of a link in rails i've made it with the gem cocoon, in my source i get this:

```
    <div class="fields">
    <a href="#" class="add_fields" data-association="answer" data-template="    &lt;div class=&quot;nested-fields&quot;&gt;
            &lt;label for=&quot;question_answers_attributes_new_answers_answer&quot;&gt;Answer&lt;/label&gt;
          &lt;input id=&quot;question_answers_attributes_new_answers_text&quot; name=&quot;question[answers_attributes][new_answers][text]&quot; size=&quot;30&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; /&gt;
            &lt;input id=&quot;question_answers_attributes_new_answers__destroy&quot; name=&quot;question[answers_attributes][new_answers][_destroy]&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; class=&quot;remove_fields dynamic&quot;&gt;Remove&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;

">Add Answer</a>
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how to call the "Add Answer" link in CSS? I tried: `div.fields.add_fields a { css: code; }`

But that didn't seem to do anything...

Regards,
Thijs

Comment: just write 'div.fields a.add_fields {css:code}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple css question. Simply

```
a.add_fields {}
```

selects all `a` with class `add_fields`.
Just

```
.add_fields {}
```

is normally enough as well.

But if you want to be really strict, you could write:

```
.fields a.add_fields {}
```

Which says: something with class `.fields` and nested an `a` element with class `.add_fields`.

you could even state that it has to be a direct child:

```
.fields > a.add_fields {}
```

Hope this helps.